# How to find merged cells in Numbers?

Tags: numbers, macos

I wish to filter a (long) Numbers sheet, but Numbers displays the message

> Filters are unavailable

> the table contains merged cells

How can I find these merged cells without clicking unmerge cells? Is there a way to do this by exporting to, say, TSV, and working in Terminal with, say, `awk`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is an easy way to locate only the merged cells in a large Numbers table.

However, you can transform all merged cells, if any, in a table to unmerged cells by selecting all cells in that table by pressing <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> while in that table and then right-clicking with the mouse and choosing Unmerge Cells in the pop-menu that comes out. If Unmerge Cells option is greyed out when you right-click, that means there are no merged cells among those you have selected.